# how to play an embeded video via jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to play an embeded video via jquery by clickin g an html elemnet so it will pop up a box with the video in it.
the jquery works but the video does not play

```
$("#disp").live('click', function(){
      var vm = $(this).attr('class');
      $("#overlay").show();
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "zoom.php",
         data: "id="+vm,
         success: function(data){
            $("#zoomer").html(data);
            $("#zoomer").slideDown();
         }
      });
   });
```

this is the flash object in zoom.php

```
<object id=0 type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data=player_flv_maxi.swf width=480 height=320>
<param name="movie" value=player_flv_maxi.swf />
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="menu" value="true" />
<param name="autoplay" value="false" />
<param name="autoload" value="false" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="flv=Barbee-Love u Anyway.flv&width=480&height=320&autoplay=0&autoload=0&buffer=5&buffermessage=&playercolor=464646&loadingcolor=999898&buttoncolor=ffffff&buttonovercolor=dddcdc&slidercolor=ffffff&sliderovercolor=dddcdc&showvolume=1&showfullscreen=1&playeralpha=100&title=Barbee-Love u Anyway.flv&margin=0&buffershowbg=0" />
</object>
```

Comment: possibly try changing `autoplay=0` to `autoplay=1` in the flashvars?

Comment: i mean that object does not display at all in the box

Comment: I think the type should be "GET" not "POST"

Comment: you are right it should be GET but i think there is something else missing because it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok it is solved. I had the URL wrong. Since it was appended, i had to use the full URL instead of a shortened one. for example

http://example.com/flash/player.swf instead of flash/player.swf